# Fisheye effect for android camera

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera

How can I get *fisheye effect* when taking a photo? I got a Galaxy S1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your native camera app does not support picture effects as the Sony Devices with JB update. So you have to go for a third party camera app. There are several good apps out there.

- [FishEye Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onemanwithcamerafisheye&hl=en)
- [Photo Effects](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.effectsfree&hl=en)
- [Pudding Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kth.PuddingCamera)
- [FxCamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ymst.android.fxcamera&hl=en)